# UITextField input and image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitextfield

I am totally new to programming and Objective C so I am sorry if I sound unclear. I am trying to create an app where the user answers a quiz with input in a text field. When the answer is correct an image for correct answer should appear. It sounds so easy but I do not know how to achieve this and so far I was not able to find tutorial or exact answer to such question. Any help is welcome and I won't give up this early. Thanks.

Comment: You should investigate a little more over Internet. Try in developer.apple.com, there is a lot of info there.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1845/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-2

It shows you how to create a simple app with a text field and image. I'm sure you can piece everything else together.

Answer (score 0):

After user entering text check with the answer if its correct show imageview else show error view

```
-(IBAction)checkAnswer:(id)sender 
{

   if([self.answerTextfield.text isEqualtoString:@"xxxxxx"])
    {
       self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"correct.png"];
       [self.view addsubView:self.imageView];
      }

   else
    {
       //show error image
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Link has a tutorial on using TextField

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_text_field.htm

customize it according to your needs..

Image can be shown using UIImageView - for this study how to use UIImageView

Hope it helps you to move forward.Try hard

Comment: I Edited the link ,sorry my Mistake

Answer (score -1):

Use this delegate method in "@Natara" 's answer.

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([self.answerTextfield.text isEqualtoString:@"xxxxxx"])
    {
       self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"correct.png"];
    }
    else
    {
       //show error image
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This delegate method will be called each time any character is added or deleted. So this mehtod is better option instead of creating a method like "@Yohan" did.

Hope this helps. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, will try and see which one works. Thank you.